# Sometimes empty connection string from `getenv` in module

Tags: python, postgresql, tornado, connection-pooling

We have a `db_connection.py` module which looks like below.

```
from os import getenv
from collections import OrderedDict
import asyncpg
from tornado import gen
from util.utils import custom_exception
import time

db_name = getenv("DB_NAME", "XXX")
db_user = getenv("DB_USER", "YYY")
db_password = getenv("DB_PASSWORD", "ZZZ")
db_host = getenv("DB_HOST", "localhost")
db_port = getenv("DB_PORT", "5432")

db_args = dict(user=db_user, password=db_password,
               database=db_name, host=db_host, port=db_port)

class db_connection(object):
    def __init__(self, **db_args):
        self.db_pool = []
        self.init(**db_args)

    # create a pool ref coroutine where we can get connections from
    # needs user, password, database, host, port
    @gen.coroutine
    def init(self,**db_args):
        self.db_pool = yield asyncpg.create_pool(**db_args)

    @gen.coroutine
    def exit(self):
        yield self.db_pool.close()

    # run a queer
    async def run(self,q):
        if not self.db_pool:
            self.init() #try again
            if not self.db_pool:
                raise custom_exception(reason='Database connection error', status_code=500)
        async with self.db_pool.acquire() as connection:
            ret = await connection.fetch(q)
            # format to match the old data types
            return [OrderedDict(e) for e in ret]

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.exit()
        self.db_pool = []
```

In the app, we initialize the db_connection object as follows:

```
from util.db_connection import db_args, db_connection
(...)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    AsyncIOMainLoop().install()

    dbc = db_connection(**db_args)

    # What we have here is a rather basic tornado app 
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(port=8080)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The problem we saw is that, and this is something I can not explain, it seems that the connection string (`db_args`) is not always set and sometimes appears to be an empty dictionary; `asyncpg` then falls back and tries to get a connection string from the linux user associated to the container via `os`.

```
Mar  5 16:59:50 ABC: ERROR:
tornado.application:Future <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x7eff6005c320>  
  exception was never retrieved: 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run  
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) 
  File "/abc/def/db_connection.py", line 26, in init   
    self.db_pool = yield asyncpg.create_pool(**db_args)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run 
    value = future.result() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result    
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info) Mar  5 16:59:50 ABC:  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 307, in wrapper 
    yielded = next(result) 
  File "<string>", line 6, in _wrap_awaitable 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 356, in _async__init__ 
    await first_ch.connect() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 126, in connect 
    **self._connect_kwargs) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1498, in connect   
    max_cacheable_statement_size=max_cacheable_statement_size) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 296, in _connect 
    addrs, params, config=_parse_connect_arguments(timeout=timeout, **kwargs) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 242, in _parse_connect_arguments 
    server_settings=server_settings) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 152, in _parse_connect_dsn_and_args 
    user=getpass.getuser() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/getpass.py", line 169, in getuser 
    return pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0] 
    KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 10001
```

Comment: Yes. The app runs in a docker container

Comment: Ok. So the error is that it tries to get an `/etc/passwd` entry for a user that has none (that must be your Docker user, [also related](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5940/)), but that's probably irrelevant. Try narrowing down the point at which the connection info is lost (does Docker even pass it to the container?). Also please mention Docker in the question (+tags).

Comment: What interests me is why ‘getenv’ sometimes fails and sets ‘db_args’ to an empty dictionary. It does not make sense to me. I do not want the app to try to fetch the user name with an os call, that is not desired behavior, I would avoid looking at this altogether.

Comment: That's the [default behaviour](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#connection), if you want to avoid it, make sure not to pass in an empty `user`. If you want to *fix* it, you'll probably have to figure out what's causing `DB_USER` to be empty (which likely has nothing to do with `getenv` and is a Docker issue).

Comment: Agreed - this is in fact what I am trying to do. What drives me nuts it is, as far as I can see, it does not happen all the time